# Como enviar comandos para o interpretador ruby a partir de um Shell Script?

Tags: ruby, bash, terminal, shell-script

Isso é mais por curiosidade... Já vi alguns exemplos do que quero fazer, mas em Perl. Tentei encontrar uma forma de fazer o mesmo em ruby, mas sem sucesso.

Quero uma função para gerar um hash MD5 a partir de uma palavra passada como argumento. A intenção é enviar este argumento para o interpretador do ruby, e então usar o retorno na função. Fiz um "pseudo-código" para ilustrar o que eu quero:

```
function generate_hash {
  # Enviar o argumento para o interpretador e obter o retorno.
  ruby "Digest::MD5.hexdigest($1)"
}
```

Alguém tem idéia de como eu poderia fazer essa integração?

Comment: Isso é vulnerável a injeção de código através da variável `$1`.

Comment: Sim, @MatheusMoreira. Imaginei mesmo. Mas como eu disse, é só uma curiosidade que eu tinha. Se eu fosse utilizar isso, seria para coisas bastante pontuais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para executar um comando direto no interpretador Ruby utilize -e, em suma seu exemplo ficaria:

```
#!/bin/bash
function generate_hash {
  # Enviar o argumento para o interpretador e obter o retorno.
  ruby -e "require 'digest/md5';puts Digest::MD5.hexdigest('$1')"
}
generate_hash $1
```

**Resultado:**

```
⟩ ./test.sh a
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
```

Comment: `ruby -r digest/md5 -e "puts Digest::MD5.hexdigest '$1'"`

Answer (score 1):

Uma ótima maneira é usar [I/O](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html) para enviar os dados. Em `bash`:

```
generate_hash() {
  ruby -r digest/md5 -e 'puts Digest::MD5.hexdigest STDIN.read'
}

echo 'argumento' | generate_hash
generate_hash < arquivo
```

Comment: Muito interessante. O que mais me chamou a atenção na sua solução foi a possibilidade de utilização do pipe.